# On Pixel 5 phones, how to re-order home screen pages?

Tags: google-pixel

On Pixel 5 phones, how to re-order home screen pages? For example, my home screen have 5 pages, and I want to swap the 4th page and 3rd page. How to do it? My Pixel 5 phone is using the default system softwares if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if Pixel phones are different functionally from Samsungs, but holding your finger on a blank place on your screen should make the entire page movable, allowing you to insert it wherever you want between other pages of apps